# Exposing ML model output to rest api

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a sample model which takes below features

```
[
    data['ApplicantIncome'],
    data['CoapplicantIncome'],
    data['LoanAmount'],
    data['Loan_Amount_Term'],
    data['Credit_History'],
    data['gender_Female'],
    data['marriage_Yes'],
    data['education_Graduate'],
    data['employed_Yes'],
    data['property_Rural'],
    data['property_Semiurban'],
    data['property_Urban']
]
```

and the result

```
{'Loan_ID': int(result[0]),'Loan_Status': result(result[1]) ]}
```

Using below code but it throws error.

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1



import numpy as np
#need to 'conda install flask' for this to work
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, request
import pickle


my_random_forest = pickle.load(open("loan_pred.pkl", "rb"))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    #all kinds of error checking should go here
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    #convert our json to a numpy array
    predict_request = [data['ApplicantIncome'],data['CoapplicantIncome'],data['LoanAmount'], data['Loan_Amount_Term'],data['Credit_History'],data['gender_Female'],data['marriage_Yes'],data['education_Graduate'],data['employed_Yes'],data['property_Rural'],data['property_Semiurban'],data['property_Urban']]
    predict_request = np.array(predict_request).reshape(1,-1)
    #np array goes into random forest, prediction comes out
    result = my_random_forest.predict(predict_request)
    #return our prediction
    output = {'Loan_ID': int(result[0]),'Loan_Status': result(result[1]) }
    print(output)
    return jsonify(results=output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 9001, debug = True)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: result[1] is the likely culprit as result has only one element

Comment: Correct.It was an issue at my end.Thanks.